# htaccess vs hard coded

Tags: content-management-system

When creating a CMS which would you recommend?

1. Making a htaccess dynamically create the pages based on ?pg=name
   or
2. Making a FTP connection to auto create each file on the fly? This means when a new page is created/edited/deleted the admin, when saved, would ftp into the site and create the page.

Pros and Cons

1. "Pro" Less files means less space
2. "Con" More continually overhead for apache to redirect
3. "Con" More space taken
4. "Pro" Less work to find file sense its created and only once loaded when changed

ALright, let me clarify. Which is the better option.

1. create index.php and have all htaccess redirect to it sending ?pg=name and then get the content from database
2. have an admin automatically ftp into a site when content is created/edited/delete and create the page so when the person types the page in its hard coded

Comment: FTP connction? What for? PHP script is ALREADY running on your server. ;]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a doubt the best way to go for your CMS is using Apache mod_rewrite. This way you have more flexibility in the future for changing the way that you want URLs displayed, and it expedites the creation of new content so that it doesn't have to be uploaded via FTP every time.

If you have to use FTP to use your CMS, I'm afraid it won't be very scalable, which is one of the benefits of a CMS.

Your 'better option' is 1. Stick to mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to, you can mix those options - use htaccess for nice names for your pages, rewriting them to ?pg=name and then load data from file or database.